# PyInstallerでDLL等の保存先を変更したい

Tags: python, python3, windows

お世話になります。
PyInstallerでDLLやPYDファイルの保存先ディレクトリを変更したいと考えています。
一応下記の英語版にある質問の1番目の回答で、とりあえず、実現できることは確認できました。
[python - pyInstaller changing dll and pyd output location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579979/pyinstaller-changing-dll-and-pyd-output-location)
ですが、この方法を用いてもWxPythonを利用したプログラムで、WxPythonのDLLの保存先を変更することはできないようです。
環境はWindows10、Python3.7です。
長くなりますが、スクリプトと実行したコマンド、エラー内容を記載します。

### スクリプト

下記スクリプトを「clock.py」として作成する。

```
import wx
from datetime import datetime
from pubsub import pub
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

class mainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, size = wx.Size(800, 400))
        self.SetTitle("時計")
        mainScreen(self)

class mainScreen(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.parent = parent

        self.clock_label = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "時刻")
        self.clock_text = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "", style=wx.TE_READONLY)

        vSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vSizer.Add(self.clock_label, 0)
        vSizer.Add(self.clock_text, 0)
        self.SetSizer(vSizer)
        self.clock_text.SetFocus()
        pub.subscribe(self.update_clock, "time_changed")
        self.clock_thread = Thread(target=self.clock_start)
        self.clock_thread.setDaemon(True)
        self.clock_thread.start()

    def clock_start(self):
        while True:
            now = datetime.now()
            wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, "time_changed", msg="%s:%s:%s" % (now.hour, now.minute, now.second))
            sleep(0.1)

    def update_clock(self, msg):
        self.clock_text.SetValue(msg)

app = wx.App(redirect=False)
MyApp = mainFrame()
MyApp.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

### 実行内容

1. 下記内容を「hook.py」として「clock.py」と同じフォルダに保存する。

   import sys
   import os
   sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), "libs"))
2. コマンドプロンプトを開いて、下記コマンドで実行ファイルを作成する。
   なお、ディレクトリが「clock.py」の保存ディレクトリでない場合は、適宜「cd」コマンドで移動する。

   pyinstaller --clean --log-level WARN --runtime-hook hook.py clock.py
3. 「clock.py」のフォルダ内の「dist\clock」フォルダへ移動する。
4. 「libs」フォルダを作成し、「python37.dll」以外のファイルを、先ほど作成した「libs」フォルダへ移動する。
5. コマンドプロンプトを開いて、「clock.exe」を実行する。
   なお、ディレクトリが「clock.exe」の保存ディレクトリでない場合は、適宜「cd」コマンドで移動する。
6. すると、下記のエラーが発生する。

### エラー内容

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clock.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\wx\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\wx\core.py", line 12, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。
[12296] Failed to execute script clock
```

### 補足

試しに「wx」フォルダも「libs」フォルダに移動してみましたが、変化なしでした。

---

何かよい方法があれば、アドバイスいただけると幸いです。
それとも「wx*.dll」を移動するのは難しいのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらく難しいと思われます。
該当のエラーが発生した行は以下の内容になっていて、フォルダ名に相当する部分まで明示的に指定されているようです。

```
File "site-packages\wx\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
```

17行目はこれです。

```
from wx.core import *
```

他の `__init__.py` のわずかな行数でも、色々とフォルダが固定で指定されている感じがします。

```
# Name:        wx/__init__.py

import wx.__version__
__version__ = wx.__version__.VERSION_STRING
```

---

```
File "site-packages\wx\core.py", line 12, in <module>
```

12行目はこれです。

```
from ._core import *
```

で、おそらく上記に該当するのが、作成された wx フォルダ内の `_core.cp37-win_amd64.pyd` でしょう。
他に類似で以下の import があります。

```
import wx.siplib
```

同じく該当すると思われるのが、`siplib.cp37-win_amd64.pyd` でしょう。

---

何か変更できるとしたら、以下の2つが考えられます。

1. 3つある「wx*.dll」を wx フォルダに移動する。
   ここに移動した場合は動作するようです。
2. 作成時のオプションに `--onefile` を指定して、1つのexeファイルとし、
   その内部のフォルダ/ファイル構成は気にしない。

Comment: お世話になります。やはり難しいですよね。とりあえず、お教えいただいた1番目の方法を利用しようと思います。--onefileオプションは便利なんですが、軌道に少し時間がかかるのがネックなんですよね。ありがとうございました。